# cannot start varnish - Running VCC-compiler failed acmetool.conf

Tags: ubuntu, varnish

I've got this weird error in Varnish 4 and I'm not sure how to interpret it.
If I try to start varnish, it says:

```
Error:
Message from VCC-compiler:
Expected an action, 'if', '{' or '}'
('/etc/varnish/acmetool.vcl' Line 3 Pos 1)
backend acmetool {
#######-----------
Running VCC-compiler failed, exited with 2
VCL compilation failed
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. This is what acmetool.vcl looks like:

```
backend acmetool {
   .host = "127.0.0.1";
   .port = "402";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.url ~ "^/.well-known/acme-challenge/") {
        set req.backend_hint = acmetool;
return(pass);
    }
}
```

I'm guessing it can't expect an 'if' in this case and the curly braces are there.
Ahy ideas how I can troubleshoot this?
I'm using this on Ubuntu 16.04.3

Comment: So what's on the 2 lines above that you don't show?

Comment: That's the entire file. This is how the file begins. By the way, I should also mention that this is Varnish 5.2.1. Even so, I saw that you'd still use the 'vcl 4.0' directive at the beginning, as per this link: https://github.com/mattiasgeniar/varnish-5.0-configuration-templates/blob/master/default.vcl

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I hadn't ended the last stanza in /etc/varnish/default.vcl, so varnish kept looking further into acmetool, 'thinking' that that's where the problem lay. After entering a closing curly bracket, it worked.

Comment: If you mark this answer as your confirmed answer, it'll flag the question as solved :)